# glDrawArrays on Android Smartphone has strange behaviour

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently encountering a very strange behaviour in my android OpenGL ES 2.0 app.
This happens when I want to draw a mesh I have read from an .obj file.
It is hard to descripe therefore here is a screenshots

[image]

And here is the sourceCode I am using for loading and rendering the meshes. There should be objects in the scene: one ball and a platform a bit under the ball (later the ball should fall  and hit the box)

Loading:

```
public Mesh(FloatBuffer vertexData, int faceCount, int shaderProgram){
        this.faceCount = faceCount;
        System.out.println("MESH: faceCount " + faceCount);
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        IntBuffer buffer = bb.asIntBuffer();        
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
        triangleBuffer = buffer.get(0);
        triangleBufferSize = vertexData.capacity();


        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData.capacity() * mBytesPerFloat, vertexData, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);


        //GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);      
    }
```

And this is how I render the mesh:

```
public void render(int shaderProgram){      
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(RessourceManager.getInstance().getActiveShader(), "vertex"), 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8*mBytesPerFloat, 0);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(RessourceManager.getInstance().getActiveShader(), "vertex"));

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(RessourceManager.getInstance().getActiveShader(), "normal"), 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8*mBytesPerFloat, 3*mBytesPerFloat);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(RessourceManager.getInstance().getActiveShader(), "normal"));   

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(RessourceManager.getInstance().getActiveShader(), "texCoord"), 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8*mBytesPerFloat, 6*mBytesPerFloat);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(RessourceManager.getInstance().getActiveShader(), "texCoord"));

    //GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, faceCount, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, faceCount*3);


    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Some more information: I am using an interleaved array with "VX VY VZ NX NY NZ U V" 8 values per Vertex. faceCount contains the number of faces.

Can anyone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong? (On my Galaxy Nexus it is working but on my HTC One X+ not, as well as on my Note 10.1)

Comment: Where is `faceCount` computed? I would try replacing `faceCount * 3` with `vertexData.length` temporarily. Most model formats use indexed vertices, so that `faceCount` to me would actually be `numberOfIndices / 3` and not the same thing as `vertexData.length`. Since you are not using indices, you probably cannot use `faceCount` the way you are trying to do so right now. `faceCount` is probably larger than `vertexData.length`.

Comment: I am counting the lines in the obj file for getting the facecount. One line is one face therefore the count of lines starting with f should be equal to the number of faces in the mesh

Comment: That is where you are mistaken. The [number of faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Face_definitions) is indirectly related to the number of vertices. Unless you are converting the indexed face list into 3 ***separate*** vertices per-face, then your design is wrong.

Comment: Therefore I am using faceCount*3 has one face has three vertices. Or should I use faceCount*8 has I have interleaved VVVNNNUV?